# NT4 Option Pack

Tags: asp-classic, vbscript

I am not a time traveller from past, but I need NT4 Option Pack to install PWS on a WinXP Home box. It seems that MS has already removed the installation from their site, but I need it urgently to run a web server on a laptop. Since it is not warez, I thought it is proper to ask here; is there a way to find that archaic web server nowadays? OR is there an alternative to run ASP pages with a 3rd party software, I need it just for demonstration so performance issue is no problem, but I must run VBScript codes with ASP (No PerlScript or JScript)

Thanks

Comment: If you're a time traveller from the past you should have brought the installation discs with you ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Baby Web Server ran just fine for me

http://www.pablosoftwaresolutions.com/html/baby_web_server.html

Answer (score 4):

Will [IIS Express](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/901/iis-express-faq/) not suffice? It will run on WinXP SP3.

Comment: And it does appear to support classic ASP http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4520960/does-iis-express-support-debugging-classic-asp

Comment: It should, but it should be fairly easy to test.

Answer (score 0):

"PWS on a WinXP Home box"
Not supported, sorry.