# IIS Express and Classic ASP

Tags: asp-classic, iis-express

I'm trying to get a classic ASP site set up on IIS Express under Windows XP.  I am able to get iis setup and running as well as setting up the site, but when I try to browse to an asp page all I get is:

```
íP÷Pèö‚le”_/index.asp18
```

Has anyone come across this problem with IISExpress?  I'm thinking it's a permissions thing, but I'm not sure what I need to set and for which user.

Any help is appreciated,.

Comment: Can you post screenshot of what you see? The jiberrish makes little sense..

Answer (score 32):

OK we've had this and this is how I've found a solution.. In our case I think it was linked to parent paths but could have been session state too...

Browse to C:\Documents and Settings\$your user name$\My Documents\IISExpress\config

Open applicationHost.config

Find the `<system.webServer>` section

Change the `<asp>` section to the following… 
By default it only had the cache and empty limits bits but feel free to adjust any parameters you don't want.

```
<asp 
     enableParentPaths="true" 
     bufferingOn="true" 
     errorsToNTLog="true" 
     appAllowDebugging="true" 
     appAllowClientDebug="true" 
     scriptErrorSentToBrowser="true">

     <session allowSessionState="true" />
     <cache diskTemplateCacheDirectory="%TEMP%\iisexpress\ASP Compiled Templates" />
     <limits />
</asp>
```

Save and restart iis express.

Comment: This worked for me. Thanks!

I was able to run ASP pages but not debug. Adding the above code without even needing to restart IIS Express allowed me to debug through Visual Studio 2010.

Comment: See my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4520960/does-iis-express-support-debugging-classic-asp/27948911#27948911) for how to set breakpoints.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is permissions issue or not. Could you translate the error message "íP÷Pèö‚le”_/index.asp18". 
If it looks like permissions issue, probably you need to provide permission to current user (IIS Express runs as current logon user).