# run classic asp without iis

Tags: asp-classic, visual-studio-2005

I need to get a classic asp project up and running but do not have IIS installed on my computer.  Is there away to run the project without it?  I currently have visual studio 2005

thanks
jason

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is something called [Abyss Web Server](http://www.aprelium.com/abyssws/) - I've never used it myself so can't vouch for it but from its description and features it looks promising.

If money is the issue, Microsoft came up with [IIS Express](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=1038) some while ago which is free to download and use and from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5297797/iis-express-and-classic-asp) looks like it's supporting classic ASP as well.

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea whether you can even get hold of this software anymore but Sun used to maintain a project called [Sun One Active Server Pages](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19636-01/817-6246/gsgasp.html) (aka ChilliSoft ASP) which allowed you to run ASP sites without IIS

Answer (score 0):

There may be some weird and wacky solutions (like a "compiler" to ASP.NET etc) out there, however I really doubt any such thing would be worth it.

I would make more sense to pursue the answer to this question:  "Why don't you install IIS on your machine?".

Comment: Thanks everyone.  I will try out the provided solutions.  I'm just waiting to have my request for IIS installation to to approved :(

Answer (score 0):

godaddy.

$5/month until you cancel it.

instant gratification

call them now, and then start building your asp app a few hours later.

why hassle with the path you are inclining towards?