# Issue with debugging classic ASP from Visual Studio 2013 and IIS Express

Tags: visual-studio-2013, asp-classic, visual-studio-debugging, iis-express

I am trying to run a website which has a mix of classic ASP and ASP.Net files along with lots of VB dlls used from the asp scripts. The site is setup and running correctly using IIS7 in Windows 7 professional machine. In order to setup debugging using Visual Studio 2013, I was following the instructions in the following [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27948911/608100) and installed IISExpress 8.0 to setup debugging. But whenever I am trying to attach the iisexpress.exe process hosting my site from the VS Attach to Process window selecting Script code, it is throwing an error and suggesting the VS installation as corrupted. Screenshot shown below:

[image]

Seems like a 32/64 bit issue but could not figure out exactly where is the incompatibility and how to fix it. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Any specific reason for being downvoted?

Comment: Based on the close vote, someone thinks your question is too broad. I don't agree.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a [Microsoft Connect issue](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/786897/update-2-unable-to-debug-0x80040154) regarding the "corrupt installation (code 0x80040154)" error. It's for VS 2012 but maybe you're running into the same issue even though you have VS 2013, in which case simply repairing VS does not fix the problem.

The OP of the Connect issue said that he fixed the problem by completely uninstalling VS and removing all remnants of it, then reinstalling VS. The steps are:

1. Uninstall Visual Studio.
2. Remove these keys from the registry:

*Visual Studio 2012:*

```
HKEY_USERS\.DEFAULT\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\11.0
HKEY_USERS\.DEFAULT\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\11.0_Config
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\11.0
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\11.0_Config
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\11.0
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\11.0_Config
```

*Visual Studio 2013:*

```
HKEY_USERS\.DEFAULT\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0
HKEY_USERS\.DEFAULT\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0_Config
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0_Config
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0_Config
```

3. Remove these directories:

*Visual Studio 2012:*

```
C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\VisualStudio\11.0
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0
C:\Users\UserName\Documents\Visual Studio 2012
C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\11.0
C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\VisualStudio\11.0
```

*Visual Studio 2013:*

```
C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0
C:\Users\UserName\Documents\Visual Studio 2013
C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0
C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0
```

4. Restart the computer.
5. Reinstall Visual Studio.

(I read elsewhere on the internet that it could be related to 32/64 bit incompatibilities, and perhaps that is the true cause in your case, but I'm inclined to think that VS got corrupted when you installed IIS Express.)