# How to debug a Classic ASP app in VS 2012

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, asp-classic

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you debug classic ASP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1138175/how-do-you-debug-classic-asp)

- I've added a New Website in VS2012 and pointed it at a virtual directory I created in IIS.
- In IIS, I enabled server side debugging
- The port for this website in IIS is 5555
- In VS for the project properties, I have the start URL as localhost:5555, which runs my site
- No debuggers are enabled in the project properties (there isn't one for Classic ASP)
- I set a breakpoint in a file which is included at the bottom of default.asp
- I run with site without debugging (Ctrl-F5)
- Then I attach to the process (IE10)
- Then I refresh the home page (default.asp)
- The breakpoint is not hit
- How can I get the debugger to stop at my breakpoint so I can debug this page?

This is pre-existing code. I'm just trying to get it working. No code critique is necessary, unless it's a bug that fixes the problem!

I set the breakpoint near the top of the first code block in this javascript method, but it's never hit.

```
function declareLogos() {
    <%   ' get logos

    SQL = "SELECT l.LogoFileName, p.SortOrder FROM InrixCustomerLogo l join InrixCustomerLogoPage p on l.LogoCode = p.LogoCode WHERE p.PageFileName = '" & fn & "' AND SortOrder > 0 ORDER BY SortOrder"
    On Error Resume Next
    Set oLOGO = oConn.Execute(SQL)
    logoerror = Err.Number
    On Error Goto 0
    x = 1  ' array counter

    %>

    <% If NOT logoerror Then %>
    <% Do While NOT oLOGO.EOF %>
    i[<% =x %>] = '<% =oLOGO("LogoFileName") %>';
    <% oLOGO.MoveNext : x = x + 1 : Loop %>
    <% End If %>

    imax = <% =x-1 %>;
    ilast = <% =(((x-1)*4)/4) %>;  // <% =(((x-1)*4)/4) %>   this is imax - 1 that is divisible by four
}
```

Comment: Those instructions don't help any. I've already done the few simple things he outlined in that article.

Answer (score 4):

That looks like server side asp building a client side javascript function? if thats the case attatching your debugger to explorer.exe is useless (unless you want to debug the resulting JavaScript function - in which case F12 IE dev tools would be easier), you need to attach the debugger to Inetinfo.exe (the iis process running your server side asp) or Mtx.exe / w3wp.exe (depending on your configuration & iis version).

For more information please see the following msdn article:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms241740.aspx

And a similar article on VS2008 (should be a similar principle to 2012):

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28792/Debugging-Classic-ASP-VBScript-in-Visual-Studio-20

Comment: The first link is not available any more and here is the message "This topic is no longer available"