# Configure Debugging on IIS 8 with Classic ASP files

Tags: visual-studio, vba, debugging, iis, asp-classic

Given a working **Internet application** written in **classic ASP** (with some VBScript) and an **IIS 8**.

Now I have to **debug** that application probably in VS2012 or VS2010.

I hear about some rumors, that I **can configure the IIS to do that**.

Furthermore when I write `STOP` keyword to the code file (in text editor) then the visual Studio will be triggered to attaching the actual debugger.

Please help me with these IIS or other settings, and **ask if the situation is unclear**.

**What are tried:**

[image]

Comment: I'd start here [Debugging Classic ASP Code](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/greggm/archive/2006/03/15/552108.aspx) then here [Classic ASP : Enable Debug mode on IIS7](http://www.sumitgupta.net/classic-asp-enable-debug-mode-on-iis7/)

Comment: These are not helped. I restarted the IIS, I run everything as administrator,i try in IE too.

Comment: So you tried attaching your debugger in Visual Studio to the IE instance running your ASP page and it doesn't break at the `Stop` command? If you followed those articles that is what you should have tried.

Comment: I attached the actual instance of IE with visual studio. I refresh the page (with cache clear too). Nothing. I take a breakpont next to the STOP => no symbols have been loaded to this document.

Comment: OK, have you check point 3. in the second link? `Select Detail Error for all modes`.

Comment: This was the default value, so yes it is chechked.
In the first link i didnt use the long macro, if it its helps anything. But i thing inrelevant

Comment: Argh, I think point 3. in the first link covers it `#3. Sadly, there just isn't any way to do remote script debugging. If you need remote script debugging, my only suggestion would be to use Remote Desktop and run Visual Studio on your server.` So unless you're running your VS debugging session on the server you're out of luck.

Comment: Looks like your best option is something like this [Team Remote ASP Debugger](http://www.remotedebugger.com/team_remote_asp_debugger.asp) but it will cost you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you debug classic ASP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1138175/how-do-you-debug-classic-asp)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to **attach** to the IIS working process **w3wp.exe** in **Visual Studio** manually. Somewhy that wasn't automatical but i saw cases on other computers when it was...

[image]

Answer (score 1):

in your iis in the asp section set under debug properties "serverside debugging" to "true".

Comment: oh its isnt work of course. If that was worked before i dont ask the question :)