# Equivalient of ISSET in ASP (Classic ASP)

Tags: asp-classic

Ok Good afternoon.

I'm Just starting ASP.
in php i do something like this

```
<?php 
If(isset($_POST["submit"]))
{
    echo "You clicked me yeh?";
 }
?>
```

Works without problems , Now i try to translate the same for ASP and i do something like this

```
<html>
<head>
<title>testHome in ASP</title>
<body>
<% 

if Request.Form("submit") ="test" then
    Response.Write("Ok Mate You Just Clicked Me!")
%>
<form name = "superform" id="superform" method="post" action="idc.asp">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="test"/>
</form>
</body>
</head>
</html>
```

And instead i get this super annoying error.

```
An error occurred on the server when processing the URL. Please contact the system administrator.
If you are the system administrator please click here to find out more about this error.
```

Please What Seems to be the error here?

Comment: Have you tried clicking where it tells you to click?

Comment: Of course yes it takes me here http://www.iis.net/learn/application-frameworks/running-classic-asp-applications-on-iis-7-and-iis-8

Answer (score 1):

You need to close off the 'if ... then'

`end if`

If you can, you can get IIS to send error messages to the browser: [IIS6](https://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/3c7830b4-df5c-41a2-9890-c201eb774c89.mspx?mfr=true) or [IIS7](https://forums.iis.net/t/1155087.aspx)

And if you are using visual studio you can also [setup debugging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1138175/how-do-you-debug-classic-asp)

Comment: You the VERY best Thanks a Million!

Comment: @RickTowers: You could also put the `if Request.Form("submit") ="test" then Response.Write("Ok Mate You Just Clicked Me!")` all on one line.