# w3wp.exe process missing "Script" type

Tags: iis, visual-studio-2008, asp-classic, iis-7, w3wp.exe

I've been trying to determine why w3wp.exe process in my Attach to Process dialog box in VS08 is missing "Script" type in the list?

[AttachToProcessVS2008printscreen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NjHCY.png)

This seems to prevent me from debugging classic asp pages. Can you please advise how to 'add' "Script" to w3wp.exe process? I am assuming this is IIS. I am running on Windows 10.

Comment: Have you tried following the steps here (from what you've written it seems you may have missed enabling debugging)? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1138175/how-do-you-debug-classic-asp

Comment: Yes, I tried that and it would not help. I've had the server side debugging enabled before. What I also tried is reinstalling VS2008 and it made the trick. It seems to me like maybe I have originally installed IDE first on my machine and then did IIS setup, instead of doing it another way around. Anyway, thanks for your comment!!!